# Erro ao tentar usar o comando psql no bash

Tags: postgresql

Consegui instalar o PostgresSQL no Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, mas toda tentativa de usar o comando psql resulta em erro.

Instalei o PostgresSQL usano o [código do site](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) que copiei para um script e executei:

install_psql.bashrc

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt $(lsb_release -cs)-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list'
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql
```

Não houve erros durante a instalação, mas quando tento executar comandos:

Comando: psql

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  role "henrique" does not exist

Comando: psql -U postgres - Pede uma senha que eu não cadastrei e não consegui achar na internet.

> psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Usando `sudo` o resultado é o mesmo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É apenas uma configuração que deve ser feita em sua instância do banco de dados, no caso o postgres.

Uma instalação padrão do postgres vem configurada com o método de autenticação via [peer](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/auth-peer.html).

> O método de autenticação peer funciona obtendo o nome de usuário do
> sistema operacional do cliente do kernel e usando-o como o nome de
> usuário do banco de dados permitido (com mapeamento de nome de usuário
> opcional). Este método é suportado apenas em conexões locais.

Sabendo disso, é necessário fazer a configuração de acesso via usuário e senha. Antes de poder acessar a instância do banco de dados com usuário e senha.

Para fazer essa configuração é necessário seguir alguns passos:

1. Fazer o primeiro acesso via autenticação `peer`.
2. Configurar a senha do usuário
3. Modificar o método de autenticação para utilizar usuário e senha
4. Testar o acesso

Os passos listados aqui funcionam para qualquer sistema operacional baseado em Unix.

### Fazer o primeiro acesso e configurar senha

Acessar o bash (terminal, telinha preta dos hackers) e executar o comando:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

Este comando acima vai alterar o usuário do `bash`. Esse comando faz com que o sudo execute o comando especificado como um usuário diferente do root. Ao executar o comando vai perceber que o terminal agora é acessado com o usuário postgres. Isso é um pré-requisito para acessar a instância do banco de dados.
[man page](https://ss64.com/bash/sudo.html) do comando sudo.

Após a execução desse comando será possível acessar a instância do banco de dados via linha de comando, utilizando o psql:

```
psql
```

Ao executar este comando já estará acessando a instância do banco de dados via o sgbd.

Agora será necessário criar uma senha para o usuário `postgres` (o usuário que está atualmente logado no banco de dados via o método de autenticação `peer`).

para criar a senha digite:

```
\password
```

Este comando será executado no prompt do psql. Vou ilustrar abaixo a saída do comando acima:

```
postgres=# \password
Enter new password: 
Enter it again:
```

Após ter criado a senha, terminamos a configuração no sgbd, para sair digite o comando:

```
\q
```

Também é possível sair com o comando `exit`, aqui serei didático, não vou utilizar o exit, para não confundir.

Com esses passos terminamos a configuração da senha do usuário.

Agora será necessário sair da sessão (bash) do usuário `postgres`. Para isso basta executar o comando `exit` no terminal.

verifique o seu terminal, veja que ele está no seguinte estado:

```bsh
postgres@<sistema>:~$
postgres@<sistema>:~$ exit
<usuario>@<sistema>:~$
```

### Configurar `pg_hba.conf`

> A autenticação do cliente é controlada por um arquivo de configuração,
> que tradicionalmente é denominado pg_hba.conf e é armazenado no
> diretório de dados do cluster de banco de dados. (HBA significa host-based authentication [autenticação baseada em host].)

Agora vamos configurar o [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) para mudar o método de autenticação para md5.

Para isso você deve acessar o arquivo `pg_hba.conf` este arquivo varia de localização de acordo com a versão do postgres instalada em sua máquina, em meu exemplo estou utilizando a versão 13. (`psql (PostgreSQL) 13.5 (Ubuntu 13.5-0ubuntu0.21.10.1`)

Com base nesta informação acesse o diretório para acessar o arquivo `pg_hba.conf`

```bsh
cd /etc/postgresql/<versão>/main
# para o meu caso seria:
# cd /etc/postgresql/13/main
```

Supondo que está no diretório correto, agora basta editar o arquivo `pg_hba.conf` os arquivo deste diretório só podem ser editados com permissão `sudo` use o seu editor favorito para editar o arquivo:

```bsh
sudo vim pg_hba.conf
```

Esse arquivo possui por volta de 100 linhas e em sua maioria são comentários que explicam as possibilidades de autenticação. O que importa neste arquivo são as linhas que não estão comentadas, elas estão no final do arquivo.
Localize as seguintes linhas:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Agora basta substituir a palavra `peer` por `md5`

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                md5
```

Após a mudança, salvar e sair.

Agora basta reiniciar a instância do banco de dados, para que as alterações tenham efeito:

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

### Testando o acesso com usuário e senha

```
psql -U postgres
```

Ao digitar este comando a senha será solicitada, basta preencher corretamente e poderá acessar o psql, agora com o método de autenticação usuário e senha. Repare que o argumento <kbd>-U</kbd> deve ser maiúsculo (uma versão verbosa poderia ser `psql --username postgres`). Consulte a [documentação](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/app-psql.html) para mais opções.

Após fazer estes passos, agora é só configurar a sua aplicação com as credenciais corretas e será possível fazer o acesso através da sua aplicação

Comment: Não funciona pois, logo no primeiro passo, ao tentar entrar usando o `psql` ja é pedido uma senha, que não faço ideia de qual seja, pois nunca cadastrei uma senha para o usuario postgres. Eu, basicamente, não tive a oportunidade de configurar uma senha.

Comment: Re-instalei e funcionou.